# Android emulator stops automatically

Tags: android-studio, crash, adb, version

I am using android studio and installed 3 emulators i am receiving an error while running the emulator

when i click on the extended control button (the three dots

[image]

the extended control  window pops up and then the emulator automatically closes itself. This error remains when previously i using Giraffe then also and now i updated my version to Hedgehog then also i don't even know what's the exact problem is.

[image]

It runs smooth for everything but not when i click on those three dots.

Comment: Seems line the emulator is crashing. If I remember correctly there should be a log file of the emulator somewhere in your home folder, search it and check if it contains info that could explain the crash.

Comment: i checked everywhere inside my home folder but can't find those .log file you mentioned my os is kali